# OroCommerce store rest api always throwing error for 401 UnAthorized

Tags: rest, unauthorized, orocommerce

I have created access token using oauth-token api for orocommerce.
using that access token when i am going to call any admin api for OroCommerce it's throwing 401.
Anyone can help?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2021:23:22:05 +0530] "GET /admin/api/customers HTTP/1.1" 401 460 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"

Here is access token i'm getting from /oauth-token api.
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600,
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJQNWI1X2hld0J5T0NUcURxaExkWjE2U19KU3l1emFOcCIsImp0aSI6IjYxZGQwYjFkZTViOTgwN2IyZTUwZjQxMGFhM2IzZTk2ZDdhZGVlODQzMzE0MjJiMDNmMTJlZmFiYmRlMDk5MzgxYTYzY2RiMzY0YjA0YzQzIiwiaWF0IjoiMTYzMDY2MTUwMC45NDM2MzAiLCJuYmYiOiIxNjMwNjYxNTAwLjk0MzYzNyIsImV4cCI6IjE2MzA2NjUxMDAuNTc0NjM1Iiwic3ViIjoic2hla2hhciIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.FoZw3EtLrQXAJXEPhzdlnYaYyurilD0Hf6x7eLpk6rMIHA0Sii455GsASVIpzxcTdznYlsCfUY6kfwaM8IWZXwvlP-9AqTP2ssHwRWMUHArLBJZed2P_DE4fiVBtcfZAJ96IfqBgl-NvFKW9ryJpSw5LxLa8KJEJEBOP4Qa2xZpfh_LXcxkcH6OD66l30Gvxy9ZpHFtqSDR7uBi3NlRQ7erfj46LdrGzddJ1wQjI7QlxoJLKt5SpNr6Wp01uxoyQ5L5gEuLlsMI9gidOKkodaqmDrr19spwVqeO8ygiSDQEd6C08EPmqMbrrOibslYndI2Iiz7WUjbB5RJEzypyq1w",
"refresh_token": "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"
}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please, make sure that you can regenerate the access token with that same set of credentials (id and secret) and retry to call the required resource.

In case you got an error on token generation, please check:

- Private and public keys: files are present by the path from config; [[OAuth Configuration]](https://doc.oroinc.com/bundles/platform/OAuth2ServerBundle/#bundle-docs-platform-oauth2-server-bundle-configuration)
- ORO OAuth application: application is active; [[Configure OAuth Applications]](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/user-management/oauth-app/#oauth-applications)
- ORO User: a user used in a token generation is Enabled and Active.

In case your token was regenerated successfully but you still get the error:

- Make sure that you are using OAuth Application (but not Storefront OAuth Application) to call resource from Management console;
- Make sure token value passed to the server in a way described in the documentation: "Authorization: Bearer your_access_token", and no extra chars were added to the string; [[Password Grant Type]](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth-password/)

In case the error still appears please provide us with more detailed request/response logs.

Comment: I'm still getting this error in access.log file : 

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:19:04:45 +0530] "GET /admin/api/customerusers HTTP/1.1" 401 460 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"